# Hosting multiple websites on AWS using route 53 and one instance

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, multiple-domains

I have two domains on the same instance.

I've already configured the httpd.conf as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dropcash.com.br
ServerName dropcash.com.br
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/dropcash.com.br"
ErrorLog "logs/dropcash.com.br-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/dropcash.com.br-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName descontos.top
ServerAdmin webmaster@descontos.top
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/descontos.top"
ErrorLog "logs/descontos.top-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/descontos.top-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**The configuration on Route 53 is:**

First domain

**NAME                --     Type          -   Value**

dropcash.com.br     --      A            -   ip(elastic ip ec2)

dropcash.com.br     --     NS            -   Values

dropcash.com.br     --     SOA           -   VALUES

www.dropcash.com.br --      A            -   sameip(elastic ip ec2)

Second domain

**NAME                --     Type          -   Value**

descontos.top     --      A            -   sameip(elastic ip ec2)

descontos.top     --     NS            -   Values

descontos.top     --     SOA           -   VALUES

www.descontos.top --      A            -   sameip(elastic ip ec2)

When I try to access the descontos.top, it works.
However when I put www.descontos.top, it goes to dropcash.com.br

Why is that happening?
How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the proper hostname in your `descontos.top` part of the `httpd.conf`. All you have is

```
ServerName descontos.top
```

and if you are trying to reach `www.descontos.top` you neet to explicitly add it also:

```
ServerName descontos.top
ServerAlias www.descontos.top
```

or just

```
ServerName www.descontos.top
```

Untill you add it, if httpd receives a request with unknown `Host:` header, it will serve the first VirtualHost, and in your case it is `dropcash.com.br` (which is why [www.dropcash.com.br](http://www.dropcash.com.br) works fine, but you should add that also as ServerAlias, to make sure it doesn't break in the future when you change httpd.conf)